# Suggestions for Productivity [with Case Management / Reminder / Scheduling Features]

Tags: productivity, scheduling

I'm looking for suggestions for a free / paid / open-source productivity / work management software for Windows. Specifically, I work at an organisation that has a number of files (500+) which requires to be tracked (have them as a list in a giant excel sheet for now) and worked on from time to time.

I want to be able to load all of file names from the Excel sheet into the app and track their status through various steps / stages that I define (for e.g. Stage 1 -> Stage 2 -> Final processing -> Closed etc.). More importantly, after I work on a file, I want to be able to set a reminder so that I can follow up on it within a custom amount of time (this is critical!). Would anyone have any suggestions? (I guess it could come close to a legal case management software but I haven't been able to find anything which meets my requirements).

Right now, there are way too many files to track manually and without automated reminders, it's really hard to follow up on them. I can't use Google Calender etc. as I can't access those tools at work. Please help!